# Entity Framework (code first) - Relation one to many

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have trouble with setting a one to many relationship in EF (.net Core) 6.

I have a table with users

```
public class UserDomain{
   Id{get;set;}
   Name{get;set;}
}
```

I have a table with messages where I want to track who has seen the messages

```
public class MessageDomain{
  Id{get;set;}
  Title{get;set;}
  Message{get;set;}
  List<UserDomain> UsersRead{get;set;}
}
```

Now when I add a migration it sets a column on the user table with an integer of the id of the message. But that is not what I want. Because then the read message switches every time I set a message as read.

I tried

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MessageDomain>().HasMany(x => x.UsersRead).WithOne().HasForeignKey(x => x.Id);
```

But that also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have one-to-many relationship you will have to have that column which will be a FK to the other table.

In your case if `MessageDomain` needs to have relation ship to many users.
You need to add `MessageDomainId` column in `UserDomain` class. - it will also generate that column in the db.

> But that is not what I want. Because then the read message switches every time I set a message as read.

You will have to update the reference on `UserDomain` each time that happens

Comment: Maybe asking wrong but I have multiple messages and want to know which user viewed the message. By adding a MessageDomainId in the userDomain I can only track 1 message (the id in that column).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment on the answer above you will probably need to create an additional table.

1. UserDomain
2. UserMessages
3. MessagesDomain

Where user will have a one to many relationships with UserMessages and then MessagesDomain will then have One to many relationship with UserMessages.

```
public class UserDomain
{
   Id{get;set;}
   Name{get;set;}
   List<UserMessages> ReadMessages{get;set;}
}

public class UserMessages
{
   UserId{get;set;}
   MessageId{get;set;}
   MessageDomain MsgDomain{get;set;}
   UserDomain UserDomain{get;set;}
}

public class MessageDomain{
  Id{get;set;}
  Title{get;set;}
  Message{get;set;}
  List<UserMessages> ReadBy{get;set;}
}
```

You will then use UserMessages to track which user read which message, you can then include the related tables in your query to get all the data.